# How is getIntValue returning the Integer value? Any stepwise explanation?

Tags: java

Question: [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/check-if-word-equals-summation-of-two-words/)
How is the getIntValue getting the integer conversion? We cannot just multiply a number with a character I guess

```
    class Solution {
    public boolean isSumEqual(String firstWord, String secondWord, String targetWord) {
        return getIntValue(firstWord) + getIntValue(secondWord) == getIntValue(targetWord);
    }
    private int getIntValue(String s) {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            result = result * 10 + (s.charAt(i) - 'a');
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `Integer.parseInt(firstWord)` , etc.?

Comment: I am just super dumb and it takes lots of time to build logic for basics so thanks I will try that maybe